# Merging and sorting log files in Python

Tags: python, sorting, merge, timestamp

I am completely new to python and I have a serious problem which I cannot solve.

I have a few log files with identical structure:

```
[timestamp] [level] [source] message
```

For example:

```
[Wed Oct 11 14:32:52 2000] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] error message
```

I need to write a program in pure Python which should merge these log files into one file and then sort the merged file by timestamp. After this operation I wish to print this result (the contents of the merged file) to `STDOUT` (console).

I don't understand how to do this would like help. Is this possible?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do this

```
import fileinput
import re
from time import strptime

f_names = ['1.log', '2.log'] # names of log files
lines = list(fileinput.input(f_names))
t_fmt = '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y' # format of time stamps
t_pat = re.compile(r'\[(.+?)\]') # pattern to extract timestamp
for l in sorted(lines, key=lambda l: strptime(t_pat.search(l).group(1), t_fmt)):
    print l,
```

Comment: Hmm, interesting and very helpful. I want to ask, what if i want to display content of the merged file according to [level]. For example: i want to display only values with [level] "error" and all levels above that. What i should do in this case?

Comment: while technically this will work, for large logs it will be incredibly wasteful, sice we can assume the logs are, themselves, sorted.   a "merge sort" is more appropriate here, if i get around to writing it i will post.

Answer (score 8):

First off, you will want to use the `fileinput` module for getting data from multiple files, like:

```
data = fileinput.FileInput()
for line in data.readlines():
    print line
```

Which will then print all of the lines together.  You also want to sort, which you can do with the sorted keyword.

Assuming your lines had started with `[2011-07-20 19:20:12]`, you're golden, as that format doesn't need any sorting above and beyond alphanum, so do:

```
data = fileinput.FileInput()
for line in sorted(data.readlines()):
    print line
```

As, however, you have something more complex you need to do:

```
def compareDates(line1, line2):
   # parse the date here into datetime objects
   NotImplemented
   # Then use those for the sorting
   return cmp(parseddate1, parseddate2)

data = fileinput.FileInput()
for line in sorted(data.readlines(), cmp=compareDates):
    print line
```

For bonus points, you can even do

```
data = fileinput.FileInput(openhook=fileinput.hook_compressed)
```

which will enable you to read in gzipped log files.

The usage would then be:

```
$ python yourscript.py access.log.1 access.log.*.gz
```

or similar.

Comment: Fine if you can load all log files into RAM.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's quite helpful.

Comment: @FogleBird If you can make assurances about your data files, such as they're internally sorted and you pass them in in a sorted order you can drop the cmp.  FileInput will iterate without loading into memory.

Comment: But FileInput doesn't have a readlines() method? Is it deprecated?

Answer (score 2):

As for the critical sorting function:

```
def sort_key(line):
    return datetime.strptime(line.split(']')[0], '[%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y')
```

This should be used as the `key` argument to `sort` or `sorted`, not as `cmp`. It is faster this way.

Oh, and you should have

```
from datetime import datetime
```

in your code to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

Read the lines of both files into a list (they will now be merged), provide a user defined compare function which converts timestamp to seconds since epoch, call sort with the user defined compare, write lines to merged file...

```
def compare_func():
    # comparison code
    pass


lst = []

for line in open("file_1.log", "r"):
   lst.append(line)

for line in open("file_2.log", "r"):
   lst.append(line)

# create compare function from timestamp to epoch called compare_func

lst.sort(cmp=compare_func)  # this could be a lambda if it is simple enough
```

something like that should do it

Answer (score 0):

All of the other answers here read in all the logs before the first line is printed, which can be incredibly slow, and even break things if the logs are too big.

This solution uses a regex and a strptime format, like the above solutions, but it "merges" the logs as it goes.

That means you can pipe the output of the to "head" or "less", and expect it to be snappy.

```
import typing
import time
from dataclasses import dataclass


t_fmt = "%Y%m%d.%H%M%S.%f"      # format of time stamps
t_pat = re.compile(r"([^ ]+)")  # pattern to extract timestamp

def get_time(line, prev_t):
    # uses the prev time if the time isn't found
    res = t_pat.search(line)
    if not res:
        return prev_t
    try:
        cur = time.strptime(res.group(1), t_fmt)
    except ValueError:
        return prev_t   
    return cur

def print_sorted(files):
    @dataclass
    class FInfo:
        path: str
        fh: typing.TextIO
        cur_l = ""
        cur_t = None

        def __read(self):
            self.cur_l += self.fh.readline()
            if not self.cur_l:
                # eof found, set time so file is sorted last
                self.cur_t = time.localtime(time.time() + 86400)
            else:
                self.cur_t = get_time(self.cur_l, self.cur_t)

        def read(self):
            # clear out the current line, and read
            self.cur_l = ""
            self.__read()
            while self.cur_t is None:
                self.__read()

    finfos = []
    for f in files:
        try:
            fh = open(f, "r")
        except FileNotFoundError:
            continue
        fi = FInfo(f, fh)
        fi.read()
        finfos.append(fi)

    while True:
        # get file with first log entry
        fi = sorted(finfos, key=lambda x: x.cur_t)[0]
        if not fi.cur_l:
            break
        print(fi.cur_l, end="")
        fi.read()
```