# Merging pre-sorted files without reading everything into memory

Tags: python

I have a list of log files, where each line in each file has a timestamp and the lines are pre-sorted ascending within each file. The different files can have overlapping time ranges, and my goal is to blend them together into one large file, sorted by timestamp. There can be ties in the sorting, in which case I want to next line to come from whatever file is listed first in my input list.

I've seen examples of how to do this using `fileinput` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6653371/merging-and-sorting-log-files-in-python)), but this seems to read all the files into memory. Owing to the large size of my files this will be a problem. Because my files are pre-sorted, it seems there should be a way to merge them using a method that only has to consider the most recent unexplored line from each file.

Comment: Can you add two lines from the input?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Why roll your own if there is `heapq.merge()` in the standard library? Unfortunately it doesn't provide a key argument -- you have to do the decorate - merge - undecorate dance yourself:

```
from itertools import imap
from operator import itemgetter
import heapq

def extract_timestamp(line):
    """Extract timestamp and convert to a form that gives the
    expected result in a comparison
    """
    return line.split()[1] # for example

with open("log1.txt") as f1, open("log2.txt") as f2:
    sources = [f1, f2]
    with open("merged.txt", "w") as dest:
        decorated = [
            ((extract_timestamp(line), line) for line in f)
            for f in sources]
        merged = heapq.merge(*decorated)
        undecorated = imap(itemgetter(-1), merged)
        dest.writelines(undecorated)
```

Every step in the above is "lazy". As I avoid `file.readlines()` the lines in the files are read as needed. Likewise the decoration process which uses generator expressions rather than list-comps. `heapq.merge()` is lazy, too -- it needs one item per input iterator simultaneously to do the necessary comparisons. Finally I'm using `itertools.imap()`, the lazy variant of the map() built-in to undecorate.

(In Python 3 map() has become lazy, so you can use that)

Comment: Doesn't this solution result in all the lines residing in memory at once?

Comment: @Peter: Thanks, this seems to work. Like Mark though I'm confused about how this avoids putting everything in memory. Looking at my memory usage it does not appear to load everything into memory, but how it does that while using a heap I don't quite understand. If you have a concise explanation, I would be interested.

Comment: @Abiel, I figured it out - `heapq.merge` returns an iterable, not a list. The [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/heapq.html) even specifically mention your use case: "for example, merge timestamped entries from multiple log files".

Comment: @Abiel, if you have a good timestamp format at the start of each line you don't even need to do the decorate/undecorate thing. I prefer [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iso_date).

Comment: the decorator will read all lines into memory before passing to heapq.merge

Comment: I agree @hoju. That part is not lazy. The object decorated is a list.

Comment: `decorated` itself could just as well be a generator comprehension if you're worried that the inner generators will get exhausted, and you can splat it into `heapq.merge` in precisely the same way.

Comment: Per @chbrown, `decorated = [imap(lambda line: (extract_timestamp(line), line), f) for f in sources]`

Comment: There is a new `key` parameter to `heapq.merge` since Python 3.5, which you could use instead of decorating the iterators: https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.merge

Answer (score 1):

You want to implement a file-based [merge sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort). Read a line from both files, output the older line, then read another line from that file. Once one of the files is exhausted, output all the remaining lines from the other file.

Comment: Actually, you'd want just the merge function from merge sort, not the full algorithm.

Comment: @Ignacio: thanks. Actually I'm familiar with the merge method from mergesort, but I'm just trying to figure out the cleanest way to implement this with python file handles and an arbitrary number of files being merged at once.