# How to export DataFrame to_json in append mode - Python Pandas?

Tags: python, json, numpy, pandas, dataframe

I have an existing json file in a format of list of dicts.

```
$cat output.json
[{'a':1, 'b':2}, {'a':2, 'b':3}]
```

And I have a DataFrame

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':pd.Series([1,2], index=list('CD')), \
              "b":pd.Series([3,4], index=list('CD')})
```

I want to save "df" with to_json to append it to file output.json:

```
df.to_json('output.json', orient='records')  #  mode='a' not available for to_json
```

* There is append mode='a' for to_csv, but not for to_json really.

The expected generated output.json file will be:

```
    [{'a':1, 'b':2}, {'a':2, 'b':3}, {'a':1, 'b':3}, {'a':2, 'b':4}]
```

The existing file output.json can be huge (say Tetabytes), is it possible to append the new dataframe result without loading the file?

- http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html
- http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html

Answer (score 3):

You could do this. It will write each record/row as json in new line.

```py
f = open(outfile_path, mode="a")

for chunk_df in data:
    f.write(chunk_df.to_json(orient="records", lines=True))

f.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't append to a json file without re-writing the whole file using `pandas` or the `json` module.  You might be able to modify the file "manually" by opening the file in `a` mode and seeking to the correct position and inserting your data.  I wouldn't recommend this though.  Better to just use a file format other than json if your file is going to be larger than your RAM.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18087397/append-list-of-python-dictionaries-to-a-file-without-loading-it) also might help.  It doesn't create valid json files (instead each line is a json string), but its goal is very similar to yours.

Answer (score 0):

May be you need to think in terms of `orient='records'`:

```py
def to_json_append(df,file):
    '''
    Load the file with
    pd.read_json(file,orient='records',lines=True)
    '''
    df.to_json('tmp.json',orient='records',lines=True)
    #append
    f=open('tmp.json','r')
    k=f.read()
    f.close()
    f=open(file,'a')
    f.write('\n') #Prepare next data entry
    f.write(k)
    f.close()

df=pd.read_json('output.json')
#Save again as lines
df.to_json('output.json',orient='records',lines=True)
#new data
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':pd.Series([1,2], index=list('CD')), \
              "b":pd.Series([3,4], index=list('CD')})
#append:
to_json_append(df,'output.json')
```

To load full data

```py
pd.read_json('output.json',orient='records',lines=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it just by using in built pandas.DataFrame methods. You need to remember about the performance in case of huge dataframes (there are ways to deal with it).
Code:

```
if os.path.isfile(dir_to_json_file):
    # if exist open read it
    df_read = pd.read_json(dir_to_json_file, orient='index')
    # add data that you want to save
    df_read = pd.concat([df_read, df_to_append], ignore_index=True)
    # in case of adding to much unnecessery data (if you need)
    df_read.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)

    # save it to json file in AppData.bin
    df_read.to_json(dir_to_json_file, orient='index')
else:
    df_to_append.to_json(dir_to_json_file, orient='index')
```

Answer (score 0):

Usecase, write big amount of data to JSON file with small memory:

Let's say we have 1,000 dataframe, each dataframe is like 1000,000 line of json. Each dataframe needs 100MB, the total file size would be 1000 * 100MB = 100GB.

Solution:

1. use buffer to store content of each dataframe
2. use pandas to dump it to text
3. use append mode to write text to the end of file

```
import io
import pandas as pd
from pathlib_mate import Path

n_lines_per_df = 10
n_df = 3
columns = ["id", "value"]
value = "alice@example.com"
f = Path(__file__).change(new_basename="big-json-file.json")
if not f.exists():
    for nth_df in range(n_df):
        data = list()
        for nth_line in range(nth_df * n_lines_per_df, (nth_df + 1) * n_lines_per_df):
            data.append((nth_line, value))
        df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
        buffer = io.StringIO()
        df.to_json(
            buffer,
            orient="records",
            lines=True,
        )
        with open(f.abspath, "a") as file:
            file.write(buffer.getvalue())
```