# Appending dataframe data to a json file without deleting previous content

Tags: python, json, pandas

Let me start by saying I am very novice and this code is probably ugly.
I'm trying to append dataframe data to a json file without deleting the previous content of the json data at each subsequent run.

```
import json
import pandas as pd
import datetime

json_backup = 'temp.json'
df_store = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Time", "Average Rate"])

while True:
   #doing some data gathering (code not included here) at each loop
   df_store = df_store.append({
             "Time": datetime.datetime.now(),
            "Average Rate": average_rate
             }, ignore_index=True)
  df_store.to_json(json_backup)

backup = pd.read_json(json_backup)
print (backup)
```

So this works as intended with all new data added to the json until I restart the script and the json data gets deleted. 
How should I proceed so that this data is kept and all new data is just appended to the json file?

Comment: As far as I've seen, you cannot. One work-around would be to load your current file (`df_old = pd.read_json(json_backup)`) and then concatenate the two dataframes (probably with something along the lines of `df_old.append(df_store)`, and finally saving the concatenated dataframe (`df_old.to_json(json_backup)`)

Maybe you could also take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30230394/6655150

Comment: Thanks Kostas Mouratidis, you are right it cannot be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**@Tamis**, please try the below code `Just copy the code(Python3), paste, run`:

> **Note:** I have taken the initial value of **average_rate** as the microseconds part of **datetime.now()** just for the purpose to test the code. You can calculate its value based on your logic so please change it.
>
> You don't need to create any **temp.json** file. It will be automatically created.
>
> Just copy the contents of **append_data_to_json-v2-py3.py** file, paste then run.
>
> Press **Y/y** to continue after each updation of **temp.json** else press any other key to come out from while loop.

#### » append_data_to_json-v2-py3.py

```
import json
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import time # {Added}

json_backup = 'temp.json'
df_store = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Time", "Average Rate"])

average_rate = 50  # {Added}
count = 1          # {Added}

while True:
    # Doing some data gathering (code not included here) at each loop
    time_data = str(datetime.datetime.now())

    # Store micro seconds of datetime as average 
    # (For test only, use your own logic to calculate it)
    # In case of 2018-06-03 18:44:56.220778 => 220778
    average_rate = int((time_data.split()[1]).split('.')[1]) 

    try:
        df_store = pd.read_json(json_backup)

        df_store = df_store.append({
            "Time": time_data,
            "Average Rate": average_rate
        }, ignore_index=True)
        
        df_store.to_json(json_backup)
        print (df_store)
        print ("***********************************************")       
    except Exception as e:
        df_store = df_store.append({
            "Time": time_data,
            "Average Rate": average_rate
            }, ignore_index=True)

        df_store.to_json(json_backup)
        print(df_store)
        print("***********************************************")

    # time.sleep(30.0 - ((time.time() - starttime) % 30.0))  # {Commented}
    print(count, "temp.json updated")

    # If user presses Y/y then continue otherwise exit from loop
    choice = input("\n" + str(count) + " Do you want to continue the operation (Y/N): ")
    if choice == 'y' or choice == 'Y':
        count = count + 1
        continue
    else:
        break
```

#### » First run

```
(py3.6) H:\RishikeshAgrawani\Projects\Python3\Pandas>python append_data_to_json-v2-py3.py
                         Time Average Rate
0  2018-06-03 18:51:57.506959       506959
***********************************************
1 temp.json updated

1 Do you want to continue the operation (Y/N): y
                         Time  Average Rate
0  2018-06-03 18:51:57.506959        506959
1  2018-06-03 18:52:00.925554        925554
***********************************************
2 temp.json updated

2 Do you want to continue the operation (Y/N): y
                         Time  Average Rate
0  2018-06-03 18:51:57.506959        506959
1  2018-06-03 18:52:00.925554        925554
2  2018-06-03 18:52:02.325613        325613
***********************************************
3 temp.json updated

3 Do you want to continue the operation (Y/N): y
                         Time  Average Rate
0  2018-06-03 18:51:57.506959        506959
1  2018-06-03 18:52:00.925554        925554
2  2018-06-03 18:52:02.325613        325613
3  2018-06-03 18:52:03.508673        508673
***********************************************
4 temp.json updated

4 Do you want to continue the operation (Y/N): y
                         Time  Average Rate
0  2018-06-03 18:51:57.506959        506959
1  2018-06-03 18:52:00.925554        925554
2  2018-06-03 18:52:02.325613        325613
3  2018-06-03 18:52:03.508673        508673
4  2018-06-03 18:52:07.772553        772553
***********************************************
5 temp.json updated

5 Do you want to continue the operation (Y/N): n
```

#### » Second run:

```
(py3.6) H:\RishikeshAgrawani\Projects\Python3\Pandas>python append_data_to_json-v2-py3.py
                       Time  Average Rate
0  2018-06-03 18:51:57.506959        506959
1  2018-06-03 18:52:00.925554        925554
2  2018-06-03 18:52:02.325613        325613
3  2018-06-03 18:52:03.508673        508673
4  2018-06-03 18:52:07.772553        772553
5  2018-06-03 18:53:52.484954        484954
***********************************************
1 temp.json updated

1 Do you want to continue the operation (Y/N): y
                       Time  Average Rate
0  2018-06-03 18:51:57.506959        506959
1  2018-06-03 18:52:00.925554        925554
2  2018-06-03 18:52:02.325613        325613
3  2018-06-03 18:52:03.508673        508673
4  2018-06-03 18:52:07.772553        772553
5  2018-06-03 18:53:52.484954        484954
6  2018-06-03 18:53:54.733274        733274
***********************************************
2 temp.json updated

2 Do you want to continue the operation (Y/N): y
                       Time  Average Rate
0  2018-06-03 18:51:57.506959        506959
1  2018-06-03 18:52:00.925554        925554
2  2018-06-03 18:52:02.325613        325613
3  2018-06-03 18:52:03.508673        508673
4  2018-06-03 18:52:07.772553        772553
5  2018-06-03 18:53:52.484954        484954
6  2018-06-03 18:53:54.733274        733274
7  2018-06-03 18:53:57.037358         37358
***********************************************
3 temp.json updated

3 Do you want to continue the operation (Y/N): y
                       Time  Average Rate
0  2018-06-03 18:51:57.506959        506959
1  2018-06-03 18:52:00.925554        925554
2  2018-06-03 18:52:02.325613        325613
3  2018-06-03 18:52:03.508673        508673
4  2018-06-03 18:52:07.772553        772553
5  2018-06-03 18:53:52.484954        484954
6  2018-06-03 18:53:54.733274        733274
7  2018-06-03 18:53:57.037358         37358
8  2018-06-03 18:53:58.437644        437644
***********************************************
4 temp.json updated

4 Do you want to continue the operation (Y/N): y
                       Time  Average Rate
0  2018-06-03 18:51:57.506959        506959
1  2018-06-03 18:52:00.925554        925554
2  2018-06-03 18:52:02.325613        325613
3  2018-06-03 18:52:03.508673        508673
4  2018-06-03 18:52:07.772553        772553
5  2018-06-03 18:53:52.484954        484954
6  2018-06-03 18:53:54.733274        733274
7  2018-06-03 18:53:57.037358         37358
8  2018-06-03 18:53:58.437644        437644
9  2018-06-03 18:53:59.181472        181472
***********************************************
5 temp.json updated

5 Do you want to continue the operation (Y/N): y
                        Time  Average Rate
0   2018-06-03 18:51:57.506959        506959
1   2018-06-03 18:52:00.925554        925554
2   2018-06-03 18:52:02.325613        325613
3   2018-06-03 18:52:03.508673        508673
4   2018-06-03 18:52:07.772553        772553
5   2018-06-03 18:53:52.484954        484954
6   2018-06-03 18:53:54.733274        733274
7   2018-06-03 18:53:57.037358         37358
8   2018-06-03 18:53:58.437644        437644
9   2018-06-03 18:53:59.181472        181472
10  2018-06-03 18:53:59.805276        805276
***********************************************
6 temp.json updated

6 Do you want to continue the operation (Y/N): y
                        Time  Average Rate
0   2018-06-03 18:51:57.506959        506959
1   2018-06-03 18:52:00.925554        925554
2   2018-06-03 18:53:59.805276        805276
3   2018-06-03 18:52:02.325613        325613
4   2018-06-03 18:52:03.508673        508673
5   2018-06-03 18:52:07.772553        772553
6   2018-06-03 18:53:52.484954        484954
7   2018-06-03 18:53:54.733274        733274
8   2018-06-03 18:53:57.037358         37358
9   2018-06-03 18:53:58.437644        437644
10  2018-06-03 18:53:59.181472        181472
11  2018-06-03 18:54:00.436774        436774
***********************************************
7 temp.json updated

7 Do you want to continue the operation (Y/N): y
                        Time  Average Rate
0   2018-06-03 18:51:57.506959        506959
1   2018-06-03 18:52:00.925554        925554
2   2018-06-03 18:53:59.181472        181472
3   2018-06-03 18:54:00.436774        436774
4   2018-06-03 18:53:59.805276        805276
5   2018-06-03 18:52:02.325613        325613
6   2018-06-03 18:52:03.508673        508673
7   2018-06-03 18:52:07.772553        772553
8   2018-06-03 18:53:52.484954        484954
9   2018-06-03 18:53:54.733274        733274
10  2018-06-03 18:53:57.037358         37358
11  2018-06-03 18:53:58.437644        437644
12  2018-06-03 18:54:00.997659        997659
***********************************************
8 temp.json updated

8 Do you want to continue the operation (Y/N): y
                        Time  Average Rate
0   2018-06-03 18:51:57.506959        506959
1   2018-06-03 18:52:00.925554        925554
2   2018-06-03 18:53:57.037358         37358
3   2018-06-03 18:53:58.437644        437644
4   2018-06-03 18:54:00.997659        997659
5   2018-06-03 18:53:59.181472        181472
6   2018-06-03 18:54:00.436774        436774
7   2018-06-03 18:53:59.805276        805276
8   2018-06-03 18:52:02.325613        325613
9   2018-06-03 18:52:03.508673        508673
10  2018-06-03 18:52:07.772553        772553
11  2018-06-03 18:53:52.484954        484954
12  2018-06-03 18:53:54.733274        733274
13  2018-06-03 18:54:01.549498        549498
***********************************************
9 temp.json updated

9 Do you want to continue the operation (Y/N): y
                        Time  Average Rate
0   2018-06-03 18:51:57.506959        506959
1   2018-06-03 18:52:00.925554        925554
2   2018-06-03 18:52:07.772553        772553
3   2018-06-03 18:53:52.484954        484954
4   2018-06-03 18:53:54.733274        733274
5   2018-06-03 18:54:01.549498        549498
6   2018-06-03 18:53:57.037358         37358
7   2018-06-03 18:53:58.437644        437644
8   2018-06-03 18:54:00.997659        997659
9   2018-06-03 18:53:59.181472        181472
10  2018-06-03 18:54:00.436774        436774
11  2018-06-03 18:53:59.805276        805276
12  2018-06-03 18:52:02.325613        325613
13  2018-06-03 18:52:03.508673        508673
14  2018-06-03 18:54:02.061568         61568
***********************************************
10 temp.json updated

10 Do you want to continue the operation (Y/N): y
                        Time  Average Rate
0   2018-06-03 18:51:57.506959        506959
1   2018-06-03 18:52:00.925554        925554
2   2018-06-03 18:54:00.436774        436774
3   2018-06-03 18:53:59.805276        805276
4   2018-06-03 18:52:02.325613        325613
5   2018-06-03 18:52:03.508673        508673
6   2018-06-03 18:54:02.061568         61568
7   2018-06-03 18:52:07.772553        772553
8   2018-06-03 18:53:52.484954        484954
9   2018-06-03 18:53:54.733274        733274
10  2018-06-03 18:54:01.549498        549498
11  2018-06-03 18:53:57.037358         37358
12  2018-06-03 18:53:58.437644        437644
13  2018-06-03 18:54:00.997659        997659
14  2018-06-03 18:53:59.181472        181472
15  2018-06-03 18:54:03.420695        420695
***********************************************
11 temp.json updated

11 Do you want to continue the operation (Y/N): n
```

#### » Third run

```
(py3.6) H:\RishikeshAgrawani\Projects\Python3\Pandas>python append_data_to_json-v2-py3.py
                          Time  Average Rate
0   2018-06-03 18:51:57.506959        506959
1   2018-06-03 18:52:00.925554        925554
2   2018-06-03 18:54:01.549498        549498
3   2018-06-03 18:53:57.037358         37358
4   2018-06-03 18:53:58.437644        437644
5   2018-06-03 18:54:00.997659        997659
6   2018-06-03 18:53:59.181472        181472
7   2018-06-03 18:54:03.420695        420695
8   2018-06-03 18:54:00.436774        436774
9   2018-06-03 18:53:59.805276        805276
10  2018-06-03 18:52:02.325613        325613
11  2018-06-03 18:52:03.508673        508673
12  2018-06-03 18:54:02.061568         61568
13  2018-06-03 18:52:07.772553        772553
14  2018-06-03 18:53:52.484954        484954
15  2018-06-03 18:53:54.733274        733274
16  2018-06-03 18:55:39.415698        415698
***********************************************
1 temp.json updated

1 Do you want to continue the operation (Y/N): y
                          Time  Average Rate
0   2018-06-03 18:51:57.506959        506959
1   2018-06-03 18:52:00.925554        925554
2   2018-06-03 18:52:02.325613        325613
3   2018-06-03 18:52:03.508673        508673
4   2018-06-03 18:54:02.061568         61568
5   2018-06-03 18:52:07.772553        772553
6   2018-06-03 18:53:52.484954        484954
7   2018-06-03 18:53:54.733274        733274
8   2018-06-03 18:55:39.415698        415698
9   2018-06-03 18:54:01.549498        549498
10  2018-06-03 18:53:57.037358         37358
11  2018-06-03 18:53:58.437644        437644
12  2018-06-03 18:54:00.997659        997659
13  2018-06-03 18:53:59.181472        181472
14  2018-06-03 18:54:03.420695        420695
15  2018-06-03 18:54:00.436774        436774
16  2018-06-03 18:53:59.805276        805276
17  2018-06-03 18:55:41.861641        861641
***********************************************
2 temp.json updated

2 Do you want to continue the operation (Y/N): y
                          Time  Average Rate
0   2018-06-03 18:51:57.506959        506959
1   2018-06-03 18:52:00.925554        925554
2   2018-06-03 18:53:57.037358         37358
3   2018-06-03 18:53:58.437644        437644
4   2018-06-03 18:54:00.997659        997659
5   2018-06-03 18:53:59.181472        181472
6   2018-06-03 18:54:03.420695        420695
7   2018-06-03 18:54:00.436774        436774
8   2018-06-03 18:53:59.805276        805276
9   2018-06-03 18:55:41.861641        861641
10  2018-06-03 18:52:02.325613        325613
11  2018-06-03 18:52:03.508673        508673
12  2018-06-03 18:54:02.061568         61568
13  2018-06-03 18:52:07.772553        772553
14  2018-06-03 18:53:52.484954        484954
15  2018-06-03 18:53:54.733274        733274
16  2018-06-03 18:55:39.415698        415698
17  2018-06-03 18:54:01.549498        549498
18  2018-06-03 18:55:44.381318        381318
***********************************************
3 temp.json updated

3 Do you want to continue the operation (Y/N): y
                          Time  Average Rate
0   2018-06-03 18:51:57.506959        506959
1   2018-06-03 18:52:00.925554        925554
2   2018-06-03 18:52:02.325613        325613
3   2018-06-03 18:52:03.508673        508673
4   2018-06-03 18:54:02.061568         61568
5   2018-06-03 18:52:07.772553        772553
6   2018-06-03 18:53:52.484954        484954
7   2018-06-03 18:53:54.733274        733274
8   2018-06-03 18:55:39.415698        415698
9   2018-06-03 18:54:01.549498        549498
10  2018-06-03 18:55:44.381318        381318
11  2018-06-03 18:53:57.037358         37358
12  2018-06-03 18:53:58.437644        437644
13  2018-06-03 18:54:00.997659        997659
14  2018-06-03 18:53:59.181472        181472
15  2018-06-03 18:54:03.420695        420695
16  2018-06-03 18:54:00.436774        436774
17  2018-06-03 18:53:59.805276        805276
18  2018-06-03 18:55:41.861641        861641
19  2018-06-03 18:55:45.181318        181318
***********************************************
4 temp.json updated

4 Do you want to continue the operation (Y/N): y
                          Time  Average Rate
0   2018-06-03 18:51:57.506959        506959
1   2018-06-03 18:52:00.925554        925554
2   2018-06-03 18:55:44.381318        381318
3   2018-06-03 18:53:57.037358         37358
4   2018-06-03 18:53:58.437644        437644
5   2018-06-03 18:54:00.997659        997659
6   2018-06-03 18:53:59.181472        181472
7   2018-06-03 18:54:03.420695        420695
8   2018-06-03 18:54:00.436774        436774
9   2018-06-03 18:53:59.805276        805276
10  2018-06-03 18:55:41.861641        861641
11  2018-06-03 18:55:45.181318        181318
12  2018-06-03 18:52:02.325613        325613
13  2018-06-03 18:52:03.508673        508673
14  2018-06-03 18:54:02.061568         61568
15  2018-06-03 18:52:07.772553        772553
16  2018-06-03 18:53:52.484954        484954
17  2018-06-03 18:53:54.733274        733274
18  2018-06-03 18:55:39.415698        415698
19  2018-06-03 18:54:01.549498        549498
20  2018-06-03 18:55:45.765547        765547
***********************************************
5 temp.json updated

5 Do you want to continue the operation (Y/N): n
```

Comment: why is there so much duplicate code and bare exception? people might actually learn doing that from your post!

Comment: **@Evgeny**, I didn't get, you're talking about which part of code.

Comment: the duplicates? most of code in try and except, if you notice

Comment: Yea, that is correct. We can design a single block of code and place it inside that but it's just 3-4 lines of code so I thought, not to make problem more complicated with 2 function calls. So it's  totally up to the programmer how he/she designs the code. Using function to remove code duplication is nice. Thanks.

Comment: Better make good programming decisions, right? Bare exception? Perhaps you know what kind of error might occur?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should read the `'temp.json'` before the start of your `while` loop into  `df_store` variable, if the `'temp.json'` file exists.