# Merging very large files in AWK dying partway through - means to avoid?

Tags: bash, unix, awk

I have to similar big (~4GB) tabulated files whose I want to relate together by a hash in awk. File_1

```
179102  179102  NP_000138.2     FUCA1   rs665   missense    I   260
179102  179102  NP_000138.2     FUCA1   rs665   missense    W   260
179102          XP_011539469.1  FUCA1   rs665   missense    I   49
105800  105800  NP_005531.2     INPP5B  rs980   missense    I   913
244463          NP_057445.4     ACP6    rs1344  syn-codon   H   413
286513  286513  NP_006163.1     NPPA    rs5065  stop-lost   R   32
```

and the 2nd file is file_2:

```
179102  179102  NP_000138.2     FUCA1   rs665   reference   I   260
179102          XP_011539469.1  FUCA1   rs665   reference   I   49
105800  105800  NP_005531.2     INPP5B  rs980   reference   I   913
244463          NP_057445.4     ACP6    rs1344  reference   H   413
286513  286513  NP_006163.1     NPPA    rs5065  reference   V   32
```

So, I want when third and fifth columns are the same in both files put the seventh column in first file, thus the desired output_1 should be:

```
179102  179102  NP_000138.2     FUCA1   rs665   missense    I   260  I 
179102  179102  NP_000138.2     FUCA1   rs665   missense    I   260  W
179102          XP_011539469.1  FUCA1   rs665   missense    I   49   I
105800  105800  NP_005531.2     INPP5B  rs980   missense    I   913  I
244463          NP_057445.4     ACP6    rs1344  syn-codon   H   413  H
286513  286513  NP_006163.1     NPPA    rs5065  stop-lost   V   32   R
```

In this way, I joint third and fifth columns for both files like

```
179102  179102  NP_000138.2rs665    FUCA1   missense    I   260
```

and then run the following script

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="\t"} NR==FNR {h[$3] = $6; next} {print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,h[$3],$7,$6}' "file_2" "file_1" > "output_1";
```

Unfortunately, I think due to the size of files the script does not work and it stop after few minutes with the next message: 
Finished (killed).

So, are there any way to do this in order to run the script will be possible computationally? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12460943/merging-pre-sorted-files-without-reading-everything-into-memory -- sort them on the merge key, and you only have to keep the data for a single key in memory at any moment in time. You'll probably have to switch from Awk to something like Python, Ruby, or Perl. (Not an absolute requirement, but the processing model of Awk tends to get in the way if you don't use it the way it was designed.)

Comment: Of course, if you have the room to store a sorted copy of each file on disk, you can probably do all of this with just the [`join`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/join.1.html) command.

Comment: If you use GNU `sort` instead of trying to have your sorting done by `awk`, it can automagically spool pieces to disk (and then merge-sort them together afterwards) instead of needing everything to fit in RAM.

Comment: (Similarly, the UNIX `join` tool can run the join in constant memory so long as both inputs are pre-sorted by the key).

Answer (score 0):

the first thing that comes to mind is storing the necessary information in a list and then consulting the list

```
awk 'BEGIN{
       FIELDWIDTHS="8 8 16 8 8 12 4 6"
       format="%-8s%-8s%-16s%-8s%-8s%-12s%-4s%-6s%-4s\n"
     }
     (NR==FNR) { key=$1$2$3$5; array[key]=$7; next }
     { key=$1$2$3$5;}
     (key in array) {
            printf format,$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,array[key],$8,$7
     }' file2.txt file1.txt
```

and this give the following output:

```
179102  179102  NP_000138.2     FUCA1   rs665   missense    I   260   I   
179102  179102  NP_000138.2     FUCA1   rs665   missense    I   260   W   
179102          XP_011539469.1  FUCA1   rs665   missense    I   49    I   
105800  105800  NP_005531.2     INPP5B  rs980   missense    I   913   I   
244463          NP_057445.4     ACP6    rs1344  syn-codon   H   413   H   
286513  286513  NP_006163.1     NPPA    rs5065  stop-lost   V   32    R
```

Here I assumed the following :

- `file2` has a unique combination of `$1$2$3$5`
- the list will only print lines from `file1` if the key appears in `file2`.

The `awk` command makes use of [gnu extension](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Built_002din-Variables) `FIELDWIDTHS` because column 2 might be empty and there might be other columns empty.

> **`FIELDWIDTHS`** A space-separated list of columns that tells gawk how to
>   split input with fixed columnar boundaries. Starting in version 4.2,
>   each field width may optionally be preceded by a colon-separated value
>   specifying the number of characters to skip before the field starts.
>   Assigning a value to `FIELDWIDTHS` overrides the use of `FS` and `FPAT` for
>   field splitting. See Constant Size for more information.

However, you mention that your file is rather sized. Since we store the key and value (44 characters) in memory and each line is only 70 characters long, we would still store about 2.5Gb in memory. If this is too much you might do the following :

- repeatedly parse `file1` and `file2` over and over again (adjust [this technique](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Rewind-Function.html))
- buffer only a part of `file2` and parse `file1` fully based on the current buffer
- finish if all records of `file2` have been parsed in `file1`

The following `awk` program does the trick. In this example `buffer_size` is set to 3 lines only. You can change this to something like 10000 or so which fits more your file sizes.

```
awk '#define function to add current FILENAME on the argument list
     function reparse() {
         ARGV[ARGC]=FILENAME
         ARGC++
     }
     BEGIN{
       FIELDWIDTHS="8 8 16 8 8 12 4 6"
       format="%-8s%-8s%-16s%-8s%-8s%-12s%-4s%-6s%-4s\n"
       start_record=1
       buffer_size=3
     }
     # if new file, add it again to the argument list
     (FNR==1) { reparse() }
     # all odd numbered arguments/files are file2
     (ARGIND%2 == 1) {
         #this part executes only for file2

         # at the start of file2, delete the buffer
         # redefine the start_record
         # check if we finished
         if (FNR == 1)
         { 
             delete buffer
             start_record = (ARGIND==1) ? 1 : start_record + buffer_size
             if (last_record < start_record-1) exit
         }

         # check if this record needs to be read
         if (FNR < start_record) { next }

         # check if the buffer is full
         if (FNR >= start_record + buffer_size ) { nextfile }

         # compute buffer
         key=$1$2$3$5; buffer[key]=$7; last_record=FNR
         next
     }

     # everthing below this line is only working on file2
     { key=$1$2$3$5}
     (key in buffer) {
            printf format,$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,buffer[key],$8,$7
     }' file2.txt file1.txt
```