# How to make stdout works with Parallel Python?

Tags: python, parallel-python

I'm wondering if it is possible to make `stdout` works with [Parallel Python](http://www.parallelpython.com/)? It's really hard to debug without seeing any print-out.

For example, given the following code snippets:

```
import pp

def printit(s):
    print s

job_server = pp.Server()
for i in xrange(100):
    job_server.submit(printit, (i,))
job_server.wait()
```

There is not any *print out*. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into using the `logging` module.  Set up your "parent" program to listen on a network port, and have your "jobs" send debug info (using `logging`) to that port. An example of how to set this up is given here:  http://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging-cookbook.html#sending-and-receiving-logging-events-across-a-network

Comment: Thank you. The similar answer was mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15096090/python-separate-processes-logging-to-same-file.