# Deadlock with logging multiprocess/multithread python script

Tags: python, multithreading, logging, multiprocess

I am facing the problem with collecting logs from the following script.
Once I set up the `SLEEP_TIME` to too "small" value, the LoggingThread
threads somehow block the logging module. The script freeze on logging request
in the `action` function. If the `SLEEP_TIME` is about 0.1 the script collect
all log messages as I expect.

I tried to follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/894284/533618) but it does not solve my problem.

```
import multiprocessing
import threading
import logging
import time

SLEEP_TIME = 0.000001

logger = logging.getLogger()

ch = logging.StreamHandler()
ch.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(funcName)s(): %(message)s'))
ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.addHandler(ch)


class LoggingThread(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        while True:
            logger.debug('LoggingThread: {}'.format(self))
            time.sleep(SLEEP_TIME)


def action(i):
    logger.debug('action: {}'.format(i))


def do_parallel_job():

    processes = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=processes)
    for i in range(20):
        pool.apply_async(action, args=(i,))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()



if __name__ == '__main__':

    logger.debug('START')

    #
    # multithread part
    #
    for _ in range(10):
        lt = LoggingThread()
        lt.setDaemon(True)
        lt.start()

    #
    # multiprocess part
    #
    do_parallel_job()

    logger.debug('FINISH')
```

How to use logging module in multiprocess and multithread scripts?

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce your problem. Can you provide the thread creation/launching code?

Comment: Just to be sure: the execution of action() freezes (log message with 'actions:' is never produced). LoggingThreads do their job forever.

Comment: The probability of the deadlock depends on `SLEEP_TIME` value.

Answer (score 8):

This is probably [bug 6721](http://bugs.python.org/issue6721).

The problem is common in any situation where you have locks, threads and forks. If thread 1 had a lock while thread 2 calls fork, in the forked process, there will only be thread 2 and the lock will be held forever. In your case, that is `logging.StreamHandler.lock`.

A fix can be found [here](https://github.com/google/python-atfork/blob/main/atfork/stdlib_fixer.py) ([permalink](https://github.com/google/python-atfork/blob/0ba186bd3a75f823c720e711b39d73441da67ea4/atfork/stdlib_fixer.py)) for the `logging` module. Note that you need to take care of any other locks, too.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into similar issue just recently while using logging module together with Pathos multiprocessing library. Still not 100% sure, but it seems, that in my case the problem may have been caused by the fact, that logging handler was trying to reuse a lock object from within different processes.

Was able to fix it with a simple wrapper around default logging Handler:

```
import threading
from collections import defaultdict
from multiprocessing import current_process

import colorlog


class ProcessSafeHandler(colorlog.StreamHandler):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self._locks = defaultdict(lambda: threading.RLock())

    def acquire(self):
        current_process_id = current_process().pid
        self._locks[current_process_id].acquire()

    def release(self):
        current_process_id = current_process().pid
        self._locks[current_process_id].release()
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, `multiprocessing` will `fork()` the process in the pool when running on Linux. The resulting subprocess will lose all running threads except for the main one. So if you're on Linux, that's the problem.

First action item: You shouldn't ever use the fork()-based pool; see https://pythonspeed.com/articles/python-multiprocessing/ and https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#contexts-and-start-methods.

On Windows, and I think newer versions of Python on macOS, the `"spawn"`-based pool is used. This is also what you ought use on Linux. In this setup, a new Python process is started. As you would expect, the new process doesn't have any of the threads from the parent process, because it's a new process.

Second action item: you'll want to have logging setup done in each subprocess in the pool; the logging setup for the parent process isn't sufficient to get logs from the worker processes. You do this with the `initializer` keyword argument to `Pool`, e.g. write a function called `setup_logging()` and then do `pool = multiprocessing.Pool(initializer=setup_logging)` (https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool).